# MonoTouch.Dialog Xamarin.Android equivalent?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monotouch.dialog

I know there is this easy way to create table based dialog easily in Xamarin.iOS called  [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) Is there any equivalent framework but to create Xamarin.Android table based interfaces this easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James Clancey from Xamarin has ported MT.Dialog over to Android. 
You can find it on his [Github repo](https://github.com/clancey/monodroid.dialog).

Alternatively, I recommend you look at [MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) which has MT.Dialog built in for all mobile platforms. Downside: overhead is big, learning curve is steep.